# Routing a Heterogeneous Fleet of Vehicles

Tags: drools-planner, optaplanner

I know it is possible to solve a VRP problem using OptaPlanner. I would like to know if it is possible to route a Heterogeneous Fleet of Vehicles using OptaPlanner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's been done before.

Just change the `(Vrp)Vehicle` class accordingly. Currently it already has a `capacity`, so you can already model vehicles with different capacities. But it's trivial to add other properties (such as `maximumSpeed`, `driverLicenseLevelRequirementEnum`, `safeAgainstRobberyBoolean`, ...).

Then simply use those properties in your new/existing score constraints.